# How to create asynchronous control wrapper?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to be able to easily create asynchronous UI in Windows Forms. I'm thinking about creating custom container control that allows other control to be hosted there. Then, when running the application, this control will display progress bar unless other controls are populated/initialized. Then, when the work is done, these controls are displayed and progress bar is hidden.

Any advices how to implement this?

Comment: you should probably provide some more details about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Panel class as your starting point.  Just inherit from it.

You will want to load your progress bar either on top of the panel or as its first member.  You can use Marquee style on the progress bar if you don't want to update it; otherwise, you can increment the progress bar as you add controls to the panel.

If you use the Marquee style, you're pretty much done.  If you want an actual progress bar to fill up from 0 to 100%, you're going to need some extra fanciness.

Here's the tricky part: the UI component updates have to run in the UI thread.  But you can't run everything in the UI thread, because the UI thread won't process events (such as updating the progress bar) until it's done adding the controls.

What you need is a method that will be responsible for adding the controls to the Panel so that you can update the UI as it's happening.  There are many ways to do this; the easiest way is arguably to just do:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(MyControlAddingMethod);
thread.Start();
```

Your control-adding method will need to marshal UI method calls up to the UI thread.  Here's how:

```
void MyControlAddingMethod()
{
   myPanel.BeginInvoke(m => { myPanel.Controls.Add(myControl); ++myProgressBar.Value;});
   //or
   myPanel.BeginInvoke(MyFunctionThatDoesTheSameAsTheLambdaStatementAbove);
}
```